# Generating SSH keys to be used on different computers

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I have 2 systems that I use almost daily. One is desktop located within office premises and another one is laptop. Both are running Ubuntu LTS linux.

I know that SSH keys generated on one system can be copied to another system and it won't break anything like pushing/committing. But I don't want to do that. **I need to track from which system I had push/committed the code**.

To achieve that I have added 2 diff. emails to my GitHub account.

```
john+desktop@gmail.com

john+laptop@gmail.com
```

Now I need to generate diff. SSH keys on desktop and laptop, but I don't know how to do that.

A friend of mine suggested me to read [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#platform-linux) article. Step 2 shows following code

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
# Creates a new ssh key, using the provided email as a label
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
```

Above command has provision to pass email address, but it mentions email address as a `label`. I didn't understand `label` part of the command.

Should below commands solve my query?

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "john+desktop@gmail.com"

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "john+laptop@gmail.com"
```

Comment: It's good that you want to generate two different keys, that's how it's meant to be done. Private keys shouldn't be copied around.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ssh-keygen manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) the -C parameter is used to provide a comment.

```
-C comment
Provides a new comment.
```

This comment is useful to remember what the key is for. On github, setting the comment to the email helps you remember for which email account you are using that specific key.

Your commands will definitely solve your problem but also theese will do the trick

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "github key number desktop"
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "github key number laptop"
```

You can change the comment later by editing the pub file with any text editor.